# How properly inject HttpContext in MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My data service layer in my API required information that are of the request in the httpcontext, I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589823/access-the-current-routecontext) and they said that I should used the ActionContext instead of HttpContext.Current (discontinue in MVC6).

The first way is to set the data inside the controller by overriding this method:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var routeData = context.RouteData;
    var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
    ...
}
```

Or using DI by injecting into the service layer

```
public MyService(IContextAccessor<ActionContext> contextAccessor)
{
    _httpContext = contextAccessor.Value.HttpContext;
    _routeData = contextAccessor.Value.RouteData;
}
```

but I'm not sure with of the both line of code listed below is correct way to do the DI

```
services.AddTransient<IContextAccessor<ActionContext>,ContextAccessor>();
services.AddTransient<IContextAccessor<ActionContext>>();
```

when I do this I get this error.

Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionContext' while attempting to activate

**Update**
project.json web project

```
"DIMultiTenan.Infrastructure": "",
"DIMultiTenan.MongoImplementation": "", 
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3"
```

Comment: remove the 1st line and retry

Comment: Apologies for the confusion but I try the code one line at the time

Comment: did you try with AddScopped instead AddTransient ?

Comment: By the way, are you using Beta3 or latest dev code.

Comment: see update question I added the project.json file for the web project. I'm using vs2015 CTP 6

Comment: I am not sure about Beta3 but in latest non-released versions, you can use `IHttpContextAccessor` for this purpose. Example: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/test/WebSites/ControllersFromServicesClassLibrary/QueryValueService.cs#L13 ...and you would register the `QueryValueService` to be a Transient or Scoped...Note that you should not register QueryValueService as Singleton as HttpContext is per-request based...

Comment: @KiranChalla I did this, please tell me if I did something worng  services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

Comment: @Son_of_Sam: you need not do that...you can check the links posted in my answer...also i noticed that `IHttpContextAccessor` is available in Beta3, so you should be able to use it..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you are trying to access `HttpContext`, then you can use `IHttpContextAccessor` for this purpose.

Example:

```
services.AddTransient<QueryValueService>();
```

---

```
public class QueryValueService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public QueryValueService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _accessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetValue()
    {
        return _accessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["value"];
    }
}
```

Note that in the above example `QueryValueService` should be registered only as  `Transient` or `Scoped` and not `Singleton` as HttpContext is per-request based...

Comment: your QueryValueService  only get query information in my case i need information from the header request collection. But thanks for the help

Comment: @Son_of_Sam: That was just an example :-), sure you can get the header information too from the request present on the context.

Comment: I made a small (but important change) to the code. I moved the call to `.HttpContext` out of the constructor. This is important because [injection constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). The call made it possible for the constructor to fail and made it much harder to verify object graphs.

Comment: @Steven if that the case, where you put the scenario where you inject a factory that produce a repository and you want just the repository, in the ctor you will set the IReposotory using a factory method.

Comment: @Son_of_Sam: That seems like an invalid use case. Instead of calling the factory inside the constructor, just inject the repository into the constructor.

Comment: @steve, this is a question that I ask regarding what I'm trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113206/change-injected-object-at-runtime, I will apriciate your input, after this I will buy you a cup coffee

Comment: You need to inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` now: `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`