# Injecting Different Implementations of Same Interface in ASP.NET 5

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET 5, I have an `IRepository` interface that I used to access some databases, like this:

```
public interface IRepository {
    IQueryable<T> QueryItems(string sql);
}

public class Repository : IRepository {

    private readonly string ConnectionString;

    public Repository(string connStr) {
        // Save the injected connection string
        this.ConnectionString = connStr;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> QueryItems(string sql) {
        // Implementation ignored here
    }
}
```

In my `Startup.cs` class, I am registering the IoC/DI like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IRepository>(s => new Repository("DUMMY_CONNSTR"));
```

That all works fine if I only have one connection string. However, how can I register and subsequently inject the correct `IRepository` if I use the Repository to connect to 2+ different databases with different connection strings?

```
services.AddTransient<IRepository>(s => new Repository("DUMMY_CONNSTR"));
services.AddTransient<IRepository>(s => new Repository("DIFFERENT_CONNSTR"));
```

In older IoC/DI systems, I would have use "named" implementations that could be resolved with something like a `[Dependency("DUMMY")]` attribute on the constructor parameter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approach that you can take one is to inject a factory and base on the specific criteria you can produce a repository, the other approach is use a Dispatcher that also produce the repository base on the criteria, below is a question that I ask with the same problem. The question below have both approach but they were codding a beta version of .net core

[See this question for reference and code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113206/change-injected-object-at-runtime)

Comment: Thanks, wish I'd have seen question yesterday. I have used the factory approach in the past, and it's probably the best solution for my needs. For better or worse, I was hoping for a lazier solution that wouldn't require me to make a decision (somewhere) as to which repository I needed in my controllers. I currently settled on putting a different "marker" interface on my repository so that I could resolve it uniquely depending on my needs, but that only worked because I owned the repository code - wouldn't have been able to do that if the repository was external.

Comment: under that question there is dispatcher example, where you make the deccicion in the startup.cs take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute StructureMap or Autofac for the default DI container (see my [blog post](https://www.jeffogata.com/asp-net-5-dependency-injection-bring-your-own-container/) for detailed instructions).  Both support "named" interface registration (StructureMap [named instances](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/registry-dsl/#sec6) and Autofac [named and keyed services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html)).

Additionally, if you target `dnx451`, you can use Autofac's `WithKey` attribute.  Using the Visual Studio sample project from the blog post, add the following dependency in project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Autofac.Extras.AttributeMetadata": "4.0.0"
    }
  }
},
```

Given a test class with the following constructor:

```
public MyClass([WithKey("logging")] IRepository repository)
{
    Repository = repository;
}
```

you would register everything in `ConfigureServices` (note the use of `WithAttributeFilter()`:

```
containerBuilder.Register(c => new Repository("DEFAULT_CONNSTR")).Keyed<IRepository>("default");
containerBuilder.Register(c => new Repository("LOGGING_CONNSTR")).Keyed<IRepository>("logging");

containerBuilder.RegisterType<MyClass>().WithAttributeFilter();
```